# Python: GUI function with 'print' no longer works after closing terminal window

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, gtk

I have a Python GUI app for Ubuntu that also prints messages to the terminal. The GUI's 'Quit' menu looks as follows:

```
def quit():
    print('exiting')
    Gtk.main_quit()
```

If I run my app in the background, and I exit the terminal while the app is still running, the above `quit` function does not do anything. If I remove the print statement, however, the app quits as expected.

So it seems like the print statement is blocking the rest of the script from running. How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

Use logging instead.

`import logging`

`logging.basicConfig( filename='gui_app.log', level=logging.INFO, propogate=0 )`

Use `logging.info( "Exiting" )` in place of the print statement, logging is the proper way to monitor an app and will not interrupt the flow of control.

Comment: this works indeed. But it does not give me custom console messages as long as the console is open. It always prefixes it with INFO:

Comment: That's because it's the logging protocol, since you're using `logging.info` it will prefix INFO because an exit notification counts as an INFO. You can use warning, error, etc. A full list can be found here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html

If you use logging properly, then you'll have very few issues debuging because it'll be prefaced with the proper message.

Comment: aye, but I'd just like to send a clean message to whomever launches my app from the terminal. As it's a python script, that's rather likely.